# Exchange coefficient in tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, dual-spaces, monoidal-categories

In the highlighted equation I don't understand why we can exchange the position $\langle a_{(2)}\cdot v^{i}, v_{j} \rangle v^{j}$ to the other element in the tensor product? Is this a property of the tensor product that I don't get?

[image]

Comment: It's just the given definition of the left $A$-action on $V^*$. The previous equation holds by definition of the dual basis' $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{i,j}$.

Comment: No, I mean not the action S, but the inner product is first on the right side of tensor product and after the equality on the left side (also after the left action).

Comment: Ah, the tensor product is above $k$ (which is commutative so can be seen to act on both left and right), and that means exactly that $\lambda a\otimes b=a\otimes\lambda b$ for any $\lambda\in k$, and the 'inner product' here is just function application, its value is $\in k$.

Comment: Hmm, for me commutativity means $\lambda a \otimes b = b \otimes \lambda a$.

Comment: No, tensor product is not commutative, only $k$ is. Forget that parenthesis.

Comment: If this is from a book or other published material, you should provide a citation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps going on: first, since $\langle -, - \rangle$ is in $k$ and the tensor product is over $k$, you move that term across the tensor product:
$$
(a_{(1)} \cdot v_i) \otimes \langle a_{(2)} \cdot v^i, v_j \rangle v^j = 
(a_{(1)} \cdot v_i) \langle a_{(2)} \cdot v^i, v_j \rangle \otimes v^j.
$$
And then by definition of the action, you get
$$
= (a_{(1)} \cdot v_i) \langle v^i, S(a_{(2)}) \cdot v_j \rangle \otimes v^j.
$$
Again since $\langle -,- \rangle$ is in $k$, you can move it around:
$$
= (a_{(1)} \cdot \langle v^i, S(a_{(2)}) \cdot v_j \rangle v_i) \otimes v^j.
$$